# Mocking a function throughout a project

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I would like to [mock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) a certain function in a utility module throughout my project, as part of a testing suite. I could of course patch and mock this function for each module using it, but there are a lot of these and it would be non-robust and tedious.

Is there a way to patch\mock it throughout the project?
If I patch and mock it in the utility module before any other module imports it, would the function be imported or the mock?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just `import module` in your script, patch it, then import the other modules that use it and invoke whatever you need to test in them. Modules are imported only once in a session; additional `import` statements use the already-imported module. So the other modules that import the patched module will automatically get the patches.